# color change for the loading bar component of materialui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[tap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8CB.png)   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKljf.png)
[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTwko.png)

```
`<Box sx={{ width: '100%'}}>
     {progress<100  && <LinearProgressWithLabel 
      value={progress} style={{background: "yellow"}}  />}
    </Box>
  );`
      
}\`\` \`
```

Someone, please help to change color of loading progress bar. I am confused.

I have tried to use withStyle, change color by css. But it didnt work. I didnt find any usefull information

Comment: This answer may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63882823/10841628

Comment: It would be helpful adding code snippet that can be run in the post.